# Find Pixel value in picture control to draw a graph

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, gdi, cdc

I am creating a project similar to task manager,[image]

Now I want to draw a graph to that show cpu usage.

My problem is that I dont have any knowledge about painting in vc++,
but my idea is that I should first make a grid like in task manager but I dont have any pixel information,
So plese tell me how to find the pixel value if the Picture control.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to manipulate what's on screen what you need to do is a create a bitmap in memory using CBitmap::CreateCompatibleBitmap and BitBlt when Windows sends a WM_PAINT message.

This question looks at how to subclass a CStatic control (ie a picture control) to draw onto a dialog by handling WM_PAINT messages:
[Handling WM_PAINT in a Subclassed CStatic Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187072/handling-wm-paint-in-a-subclassed-cstatic-control)

You just need to add the bitmap painting bit.